# Setup created using Inno Setup 6.0.3 does not auto-restart Windows 2019 with default UAC settings

Tags: inno-setup, windows-server-2019

I have created a setup using Inno Setup 6.0.3 which requries to automatically restart Windows 2019 Server at the end.

However if the UAC setting are set as follows -
       User Account Control Setting: Notify me only when apps try to make changes to my computer (default)

And the user starts the setup by **double clicking** on the setup file in Windows explorer and then chooses  "Yes, restart the computer now" then I get the following error - 
      "Setup was unable to restart the computer. Please do this manually"

I have included the required [Setup] directives PrivilegesRequired and AlwaysRestart

```
[Setup]
PrivilegesRequired=admin

ChangesEnvironment=yes
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
DefaultDirName=test\MyProduct

AlwaysRestart=yes
```

The setup log does show that Inno setups code to restart Windows is called.

```
2019-11-25 01:28:22.755   Process exit code: 1
2019-11-25 01:28:22.976   Need to restart Windows? Yes
2019-11-25 01:28:25.083   Deinitializing Setup.
2019-11-25 01:28:25.087   Restarting Windows.
2019-11-25 01:28:25.098   Log closed.
```

However the API ExitWindows fails since inno setup failed to elevate permission hence Windows does not start and the above mentioned error message is shown.

**Note:**

- Also if I explicilty run the setup by right click "Run as admin" then the automatic restart works fine.
- If UAC is turned off i.e set to "Never notify..." then auto restart works even when user starts the setup by double clicking on the setup file in Windows explore.

**Is this a known issue OR am I missing something in the [Setup] directives?**

**Complete Logs FAILED:**

`2019-11-25 01:28:19.079   Log opened. (Time zone: UTC-08:00)
2019-11-25 01:28:19.079   Setup version: Inno Setup version 6.0.3 (u)
2019-11-25 01:28:19.079   Original Setup EXE: C:\viren\Output\mysetup.exe
2019-11-25 01:28:19.079   Setup command line: /SL5="$5065A,721408,721408,C:\viren\Output\mysetup.exe" /SPAWNWND=$C0662 /NOTIFYWND=$3A0222  /ALLUSERS
2019-11-25 01:28:19.080   Compatibility mode: Yes (Installer)
2019-11-25 01:28:19.080   Windows version: 10.0.17763  (NT platform: Yes)
2019-11-25 01:28:19.080   64-bit Windows: Yes
2019-11-25 01:28:19.080   Processor architecture: x64
2019-11-25 01:28:19.080   User privileges: Administrative
2019-11-25 01:28:19.082   Administrative install mode: Yes
2019-11-25 01:28:19.083   Install mode root key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
2019-11-25 01:28:19.083   64-bit install mode: No
2019-11-25 01:28:19.087   Created temporary directory: C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\is-7REUJ.tmp
2019-11-25 01:28:21.790   Calling RestartManager's RmGetList.
2019-11-25 01:28:21.800   RmGetList finished successfully.
2019-11-25 01:28:21.800   RestartManager found no applications using one of our files.
2019-11-25 01:28:21.820   Starting the installation process.
2019-11-25 01:28:21.829   Directory for uninstall files: C:\Program Files (x86)\MyOrg
2019-11-25 01:28:21.839   Will append to existing uninstall log: C:\Program Files (x86)\MyOrg\unins000.dat
2019-11-25 01:28:21.880   -- File entry --
2019-11-25 01:28:21.881   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\MyOrg\unins000.exe
2019-11-25 01:28:21.884   Time stamp of our file: 2019-11-25 01:28:18.741
2019-11-25 01:28:21.884   Dest file exists.
2019-11-25 01:28:21.884   Time stamp of existing file: 2019-11-25 01:25:14.078
2019-11-25 01:28:21.885   Version of our file: 51.1052.0.0
2019-11-25 01:28:22.111   Version of existing file: 51.1052.0.0
2019-11-25 01:28:22.111   Installing the file.
2019-11-25 01:28:22.203   Leaving temporary file in place for now.
2019-11-25 01:28:22.205   Saving uninstall information.
2019-11-25 01:28:22.205   Renaming uninstaller.
2019-11-25 01:28:22.207   Deleting uninstall key left over from previous administrative 32-bit install.
2019-11-25 01:28:22.207   Creating new uninstall key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{0940EFBB-D1FC-4C6F-91E0-996D9E40B2A5}_is1
2019-11-25 01:28:22.208   Writing uninstall key values.
2019-11-25 01:28:22.210   Detected previous non administrative install? No
2019-11-25 01:28:22.210   Detected previous administrative 64-bit install? No
2019-11-25 01:28:22.216   Installation process succeeded.
2019-11-25 01:28:22.230   -- Run entry --
2019-11-25 01:28:22.230   Run as: Current user
2019-11-25 01:28:22.230   Type: Exec
2019-11-25 01:28:22.230   Filename: certutil
2019-11-25 01:28:22.230   Parameters: -f -p xyz -importpfx "C:\MyOrg\NMX\CertFiles\Some-Certificate.pfx"
2019-11-25 01:28:22.462   Process exit code: 0
2019-11-25 01:28:22.463   -- Run entry --
2019-11-25 01:28:22.463   Run as: Current user
2019-11-25 01:28:22.463   Type: Exec
2019-11-25 01:28:22.463   Filename: netsh
2019-11-25 01:28:22.463   Parameters: http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:443 certhash=458A6AXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxxxxx84059B8 appid={7CE058D3-892A-4318-9D3C-41FA3D8C6CE2}
2019-11-25 01:28:22.755   Process exit code: 1
2019-11-25 01:28:22.976   Need to restart Windows? Yes
2019-11-25 01:28:25.083   Deinitializing Setup.
2019-11-25 01:28:25.087   Restarting Windows.
2019-11-25 01:28:25.098   Log closed.`

**Complete logs WORKING**

`2019-11-25 05:08:50.911   Log opened. (Time zone: UTC-08:00)
2019-11-25 05:08:50.911   Setup version: Inno Setup version 6.0.3 (u)
2019-11-25 05:08:50.911   Original Setup EXE: C:\viren\Output\mysetup.exe
2019-11-25 05:08:50.911   Setup command line: /SL5="$22031A,721408,721408,C:\viren\Output\mysetup.exe" 
2019-11-25 05:08:50.912   Compatibility mode: Yes (Installer)
2019-11-25 05:08:50.912   Windows version: 10.0.17763  (NT platform: Yes)
2019-11-25 05:08:50.912   64-bit Windows: Yes
2019-11-25 05:08:50.912   Processor architecture: x64
2019-11-25 05:08:50.912   User privileges: Administrative
2019-11-25 05:08:50.913   Administrative install mode: Yes
2019-11-25 05:08:50.913   Install mode root key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
2019-11-25 05:08:50.913   64-bit install mode: No
2019-11-25 05:08:50.917   Created temporary directory: C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\is-9VKDA.tmp
2019-11-25 05:08:53.798   Calling RestartManager's RmGetList.
2019-11-25 05:08:53.810   RmGetList finished successfully.
2019-11-25 05:08:53.810   RestartManager found no applications using one of our files.
2019-11-25 05:08:53.833   Starting the installation process.
2019-11-25 05:08:53.840   Directory for uninstall files: C:\Program Files (x86)\MyOrg
2019-11-25 05:08:53.856   Will append to existing uninstall log: C:\Program Files (x86)\MyOrg\unins000.dat
2019-11-25 05:08:53.861   -- File entry --
2019-11-25 05:08:53.862   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\MyOrg\unins000.exe
2019-11-25 05:08:53.865   Time stamp of our file: 2019-11-25 05:08:50.653
2019-11-25 05:08:53.865   Dest file exists.
2019-11-25 05:08:53.865   Time stamp of existing file: 2019-11-25 01:28:18.741
2019-11-25 05:08:53.865   Version of our file: 51.1052.0.0
2019-11-25 05:08:54.165   Version of existing file: 51.1052.0.0
2019-11-25 05:08:54.166   Installing the file.
2019-11-25 05:08:54.305   Leaving temporary file in place for now.
2019-11-25 05:08:54.309   Saving uninstall information.
2019-11-25 05:08:54.309   Renaming uninstaller.
2019-11-25 05:08:54.313   Deleting uninstall key left over from previous administrative 32-bit install.
2019-11-25 05:08:54.314   Creating new uninstall key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{0940EFBB-D1FC-4C6F-91E0-996D9E40B2A5}_is1
2019-11-25 05:08:54.315   Writing uninstall key values.
2019-11-25 05:08:54.316   Detected previous non administrative install? No
2019-11-25 05:08:54.316   Detected previous administrative 64-bit install? No
2019-11-25 05:08:54.325   Installation process succeeded.
2019-11-25 05:08:54.347   -- Run entry --
2019-11-25 05:08:54.347   Run as: Current user
2019-11-25 05:08:54.347   Type: Exec
2019-11-25 05:08:54.347   Filename: certutil
2019-11-25 05:08:54.347   Parameters: -f -p xyz -importpfx "C:\MyOrg\NMX\CertFiles\Some-Certificate.pfx"
2019-11-25 05:08:54.542   Process exit code: 2147942402
2019-11-25 05:08:54.544   -- Run entry --
2019-11-25 05:08:54.544   Run as: Current user
2019-11-25 05:08:54.544   Type: Exec
2019-11-25 05:08:54.545   Filename: netsh
2019-11-25 05:08:54.545   Parameters: http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:443 certhash=xxxxxxxxdffdsafdsfdsafsafsdafsa appid={7CE058D3-892A-4318-9D3C-41FA3D8C6CE2}
2019-11-25 05:08:55.150   Process exit code: 1
2019-11-25 05:08:55.365   Need to restart Windows? Yes
2019-11-25 05:08:57.032   Deinitializing Setup.
2019-11-25 05:08:57.037   Restarting Windows.
2019-11-25 05:08:57.050   Log closed.`

Comment: So do I understand correctly that the actual problem, is that the installer does not ask for Administrator permissions (and not that it does not restart the machine)? + Can we see a complete log file?

Comment: The setup does ask for Administrator permissions after double clicking to launch the setup, the issue is that at the end when attempting to restart Windows it fails.

Comment: So what does this mean? *"However the API ExitWindows fails **since inno setup failed to elevate permission**"*

Comment: I had a look at the code of Inno setup and figured out that ExitWindows API  is used for restarting Windows.  The function - procedure DeinitSetup(const AllowCustomSetupExitCode: Boolean); internally calls function RestartComputer: Boolean; which finally calls ExitWindows. Adn the API ExitWindows needs Administrator privilages. This is here it fails and i get the error ""Setup was unable to restart the computer. Please do this manually""

Comment: But how did you infer that *"inno setup failed to elevate permission"*, if Inno Setup actually asked for the permissions? + You still didn't show us log file (also can you show log file also for the "run as admin" scenario?)

Comment: I inferred that inno setup failed to elevate permission - by running the following cases: #1:  I explicilty run the setup by right click "Run as admin" then the automatic restart works fine.  #2 I created a new Win32 EXE that has manifest file for admin mode i.e. the shield icon is displayed on the exe - and i launched the setup exe from inside this win32 API - then also the auto restart worked fine.

Comment: Added the logs complete in the original query.

Comment: Please post logs as **text**, not as an image +  I can see only one log anyway.

Comment: Posted logs as text - let me know if you need any more information. Thanks for your prompt help Martin.

Comment: There's still only one log. Can you post both logs, when it does not work, and when it works? (when you run the server "as admin")

Comment: Added the logs - When the setup is started by choosing "Run as administrator"  in windows explorer and when the the user chooses "Yes, restart the computer now" option then installation completed - then the Computer successfully restarted.

Comment: You can see that both logs have `User privileges: Administrative` - So both instances run with administrative privileges -- For a test did you try running `shutdown` command from the setup to restart the machine? If nothing else, it may give you a reason why  the restart is prevented.